# How to remove space at top of <p> tag / align contained text to top of container?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, paragraph, text-align

This is undoubtedly a stupid question but i'm having a bad day and it's confusing me!

If you view http://jsfiddle.net/E6kGP/1/ then you can see 2 simple divs next to each other each of which contains a p tag each with different font sizes and matching line-heights.

There is a small gap between the top of the p container and the top of the contained text which is different depending on the font sizes (and line-heights). This means that the top of the text in each p is not vertically aligned. If the line-heights didn't match the font-sizes then I could understand this but surely if they are the same then the line-heights should match the tallest character and hence the highest point of the first line should be the top of the p container? Obviously this can be hacked using padding/margins or absolute positioning but i would like to understand why this doesn't work by default and what the correct way is to fix it?

As requested by SO the code from jsfiddle is also below:

```
div {float: left; width: 50%;}
p {margin:0 0 1em;padding:0;}
#left p {line-height:36px;font-size:36px;}
#right p {line-height:16px;font-size:16px;}

<div id="left">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</div>
<div id="right">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</div>
```

Thanks very much as ever everyone!

Comment: I didn't see any space on the top in your fiddle.....

Comment: It's there you just have to look closely, it's only a few pixels off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be to accommodate accented characters, try putting Ä into the first `<p>`, the extra space helps accommodate the accent. That said, I'm not 100% convinced that is the definitive reason.

You can always specifically target the first line of a `<p>` element to reduce it using:

```
p::first-line {
    line-height: 0.8em;
}
```

Though granted, that doesnt solve the 'why' issue.

Comment: I've seen a question like this before (but can't find it...), and they said that that was the reason.

Comment: a random query.....doesn't the `<p>` height or any divs height will be on the basis of the content....and not on `assumed` characters basis(like accented characters which u mentioned ) which are not in the content...????

Comment: @Mayank that would be my supposition too, searching about I've found no clear answer to this, maybe browser rendering could be a factor?

Comment: Thanks ExtPro, that does explain the space, i've tried adding a Ä as you suggest and the top of the accents align vertically so that explains why it's happening! does everyone think the firstline line-height solution is the best, this will obviously vary between browsers but to be fair i can't really see another alternative (apart from the one from BeatAlex below which has the same issues)?

Comment: @deshg, I've been looking around for more info for the last day but afraid havent been able to turn up anything further

Comment: @ExtPro : check this, i asked about the same, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244305/why-browsers-reserve-space-for-accented-characters-even-if-there-is-not-one

Comment: @BeatAlex : only one user can be notified in a comment, so putting you in different comment....check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244305/why-browsers-reserve-space-for-accented-characters-even-if-there-is-not-one :)

Answer (score 1):

Like ExtPro has said, it's to accommodate accented characters. A simple work around is to have `margin-top:-<number>px;` so that you manually align it.

Comment: Not a real solution, as fonts (especially web fonts) can be handled very differently by browsers. You should rather have your design mitigate the issue. Why are you using two different font-sizes next to each other?

Comment: Yeah it's by no means the best solution, or even a good one. What I meant by 'simple work around' is not that it 'fixes' the issue, but that you can align them manually easily. @DamonGant

Comment: As Damon says this will display differently across different browsers (but then so will ExtPro's solution, but less so). In response to Damon's questions about why we're doing this it's because this is how the design agency want it to be laid out